# COMO SOMAR O VALOR DE UMA COLUNA PRO CLIENTE

Tags: java, mysql, query, sql-select, relatório

Boa tarde Senhores,
Em beneficio de meus estudos estou desenvolvendo um simples sistema de vendas e já estou na parte dos relatórios.

A minha duvida é a seguinte : Como fazer um select que some a quantidade por cliente. Seguinte, no mesmo dia um cliente pode comprar diversas vezes o mesmo produto, gostaria de saber como faço para exibir apenas uma vez esse cliente com a quantidade total de compra naquele dia.

No momento meu select esta assim:

```
select id_venda as "Cod Venda", pro_nome as "Produto", ven_pro_quantidade as "Quantidade",
 nome_cli as "Cliene", ven_dataVenda as "Data" from tblvendas
INNER JOIN tblclientes
ON tblvendas.fk_cliente = tblclientes.idCliente
INNER JOIN tblvendas_produtos
ON tblvendas.id_venda = tblvendas_produtos.fk_id_venda
INNER JOIN tblproduto
ON tblvendas_produtos.fk_id_produto = tblproduto.id_produto
```

Me dando o seguinte resultado :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para um melhor explicação, vamos pegar o SUCO DE PERA que fez varias compras no dia 25/11/19, preciso que exiba o SUCO DE PERA apenas uma vez somando a quantidade que ele comprou no dia. (SUCO DE PERA e demais Clientes que estiverem na mesma condição)

Comment: Utilize a cláusula `GROUP BY cliente, produto, data` e na lista do `SELECT` utilize a função de agregação `SUM(quantidade)`. Note que não terá muito sentido a coluna `Cod Venda`.

Comment: @Marcos Alexandre: Mas não foi o que o autor da pergunta pediu? Veja o último parágrafo da pergunta. Tá certo que o nome de cliente utilizado como exemplo não foi uma boa escolha.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema?

Answer (score 1):

```
select pro_nome
    , sum(ven_pro_quantidade)
    , ven_dataVenda
from
    tblvendas as a
    INNER JOIN tblclientes as b ON a.fk_cliente = b.idCliente
    INNER JOIN tblvendas_produtos as c ON a.id_venda = c.fk_id_venda
    INNER JOIN tblproduto as d ON c.fk_id_produto = d.id_produto
GROUP BY pro_nome, ven_dataVenda
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso deve ajudar: para a quantidade fazemos a soma (sum), e os outros campos são agrupados, no caso pode ser pelo nome do campo ou pela ordem que aparecem na lista de seleção:

```
select
    id_venda as "Cod Venda", 
    pro_nome as "Produto", 
    sum(ven_pro_quantidade) as "Quantidade",
    nome_cli as "Cliene", 
    ven_dataVenda as "Data" 
from
    tblvendas
    INNER JOIN tblclientes ON tblvendas.fk_cliente = tblclientes.idCliente
    INNER JOIN tblvendas_produtos ON tblvendas.id_venda = tblvendas_produtos.fk_id_venda
    INNER JOIN tblproduto ON tblvendas_produtos.fk_id_produto =         tblproduto.id_produto
GROUP BY 1, 2, 4, 5
```